# convert this lines of delegate from c# to vb .net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Here I have a code from Fleck that actually works fine in the C# (no errors)
and this is a line in a class library:

`public Action<List<byte>> ReceiveData = delegate { };`

then I convert it to vb .net using http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

and it resulted:

```
Public ReceiveData As Action(Of List(Of Byte)) = Function() Do

End Function
```

but error occurs:

Do -> Expression Expected

End Function -> End Function must be preceded by a matching Function

can someone tell me what is the valid vb .net code for that?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Public ReceiveData As Action(Of List(Of Byte)) = Sub() 
End Sub
```

For convertions try to use SharpDevelop. It can convert between C#, IronPython, Ruby and VB.NET

Comment: It's good but why id doesn't throw an exception? Shouldn't it be `Public ReceiveData As Action(Of List(Of Byte)) = Sub(input)` 
`End Sub`

Comment: it works, but would it be the same as the one in c#? because it doesn't say anything about delegate

Comment: I've tried converting the code in the SharpDevelop, It will likely to work fine, thanks!

Comment: Actually I dont know VB.NET. I know great tool (SharpDevelop). And I always use it when I need to convert VB.NET code into C#. So I just know answer :)